# Ruby Rails update two different table columns using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my newbie story,

my table looks like this:

```
  create_table "books", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "count"
    t.integer  "id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal   "money"
  end
```

user can create many books, and user using these forms to update it:

to update money:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :money, :value => @user.money %>
<% end %>
```

to update book title, count etc., for each books:

```
<% @book.each do |book| %>
    <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
        <%= f.number_field :count %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and im trying to do is i want update both of them. (lets say user need to update money and book title) currently it only able to update money or book info separately

model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :title, :id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that simple to explain in a single answer. I suggest you to have a look at the following Railscasts to get an idea.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised